# Set observable value with another observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have this model:

```
self.model {
   items: {
       Number: ko.observable(),
       Name: ko.observable(),
       NumberTwo: ko.computed(function () {
          return self.model.items.Number();
       })
   }
}
```

I need to initialize `NumberTwo` with the value on `Number` so I created a computed observable, but it gives me an error on the `return` line. Is anything wrong with this? Probably because I'm not referring the observable `Number` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the computed is executed when you create it, at which time `self.model` is not populated. You can use [the `deferEvaluation` option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html#constructing-a-computed-observable) to make it wait until it is accessed, or you can create the computed after the model has been initialized. To use it, you have to specify your function as the `read` element of the parameter object.

```
NumberTwo: ko.computed({
  read: function () {
    return self.model.items.Number();
  },
  deferEvaluation: true
});
```

Update: If you want to add a `write` function to the computed, it could be

```
write: function (newValue) {
  self.model.items.Number(newValue);
}
```

But at this point, you've just made it an alias for Number, which would be better done like this:

```
self.model = {
   items: {
       Number: ko.observable(),
       Name: ko.observable()
   }
};

self.model.items.NumberTwo: self.model.items.Number;
```

Comment: awesome!, now is asking me to define a write option, what should I put in the write in case I need to modify the NumberTwo variable?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @RoyJ's answer, I prefer using the Constructor Function pattern, which can feel similar to using classes in OO languages. For example:

```
var Items = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.number = ko.observable();
  self.name = ko.observable();
  self.numberTwo = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return self.number();
    },
    write: function(newValue) {
      console.log(newValue); // Or whatever
      self.number(newValue);
    }
  });
};

var Model = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = new Items();
};

var Root = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.model = new Model();
};

ko.applyBindings(new Root());
```

Naming convention wise, I advise using PascalCase for constructor functions, and camelCase for members and variables.

With this pattern, you're being more SOLID, having `numberTwo` encapsulated inside `Items` view models, and not having to refer two steps up the `$parent` tree to get to the sibling proeprty `number`.